# Instagram oAuth login with Facebook account

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, instagram, instagram-api

I'm trying to build a connection to the Instagram API using the instagram-oauth gem. However, when I open the oauth url, I'm not able to log into my Instagram account via Facebook. Only username/password is shown. Do I have to activate Facebook login support?

Comment: Could you show us your implementation of the code? Generally speaking, Facebook likes to know what applications are using their login credentials which usually involves configurations on their developer site letting them know what your application is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instagram's API **requires** OAuth 2.0 and it does not support logging in to Instagram with Facebook. OAuth launches the Instagram login via a prebuilt, un-editable web browser, so this functionality is **not** possible at this point in time.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe Instagram's API lacks such basic functionality.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but I've just ran into an issue with their oauth. If you happen to open a link from their latest instagram app, on ios you won't even be able to login this way... login page doesn't even load.

Comment: @FDIM I'm not sure I understand what you're experiencing.. Are you attempting to open an Instagram profile link and it's failing? Also, which platform are you experiencing the loading issues?

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for answering. This is a huuuge problem for me, and for many other developers as well I think. Where did you get this info from? Instagram won't reply to my emails and I can't find any other sources